# How do I reset/clean-up request args in flask application

Tags: python, flask

I have a small flask application, and in my html page I have links like:

```
<a href="/manage_items?delete=item_1"> Delete </a>
```

My Flask application handle the request as follows:

```
@app.route('/manage_items', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def manage_items():   
    delete_action = request.args.get("delete", None)
    if delete_action is not None:
        print("Deleting  {} ".format(delete_action)) # Do something
    return render_template('manage_items.html')
```

My problem is that when the page is returned after the render_template, in my URL I see the old delete action, something like:

```
http://my-address/manage_items?delete=item_1
```

If I hit refresh it will try to delete the object again. This is an unwanted behaviour. How do I reset/clean-up flask request from old args?

Comment: An idea might be to use a `redirect`.

Comment: Never use a link for an action that modifies your database, especially with a delete. What happens when Google crawls that URL?

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are absolutely right, thanks for the tip, I will rethink the structure.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I would like to pass in GET argument how user get on my page. Something like ?source=linkedin. It will then increase counter in my database, is it bad idea?

Comment: @Wuszt, no it is not a bad idea. I am not sure how you can get that information, but if you can do that, you can get the parameter and do whatever you like with it. Of course if a crawler visiting your page will increase the corresponding counter, you'll probably want to deal with the scenario, based on how you get the source website information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `redirect` for that:

```
from flask import redirect

# ...

@app.route('/manage_items', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def manage_items():   
    delete_action = request.args.get("delete", None)
    if delete_action is not None:
        print("Deleting  {} ".format(delete_action)) # Do something
        # redirecting to the *same page*, but without parameters
        return redirect(request.path,code=302)
    return render_template('manage_items.html')
```

So here instead of offering the rendered template, you return a redirect request, the browser will then fetch the page `/manage_items`, but without the parameters.

Nevertheless, as [@DanielRoseman says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924845/how-do-i-reset-clean-up-request-args-in-flask-application/42924968#comment72947306_42924845), it is usually **not** a good idea to encode requests with side-effects in a URL. A crawler, like the ones from Google, will usually analyze your page, and visit *every* URL. So that means crawlers will accidentally remove objects in this scenario. You better use POST for that.